# Sequelize: inputValue cannot be an array or an object

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I'm trying to create an instance with associations.

I am passing instances of multiple creates to pass down its values.

```
const newTemplate = await productTemplate.create({
        friendlyName,
        isActive: true,
        productCode,
        inscoCode,
    }).then((productTemplate) => {

        // Creating Form Input instance
        formInput.create({
            inputName
        }).then((formInput) => {

            // Creating Form Input Values Instance
            formInputValue.create({
                formInputID: formInput.id,
                inputValue: {
                    [Op.in]: inputValues
                }
            }).then((formInputValue) => {

                // Creating Product Template Instance
                productTemplateInput.create({
                    productTemplateID: productTemplate.id,
                    formInputID: formInput.id,
                    isRequired: true
                }).then((productTemplateInput) => {

                    // Creating Product Template Input Instance
                    productTemplateInputValue.create({
                        productTemplateInputID: productTemplateInput.id,
                        formInputValueID: formInputValue.id,
                        isDefault: true
                    })
                })
            })
        })
    });
```

Here is my formInputValue model.

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
    return sequelize.define('formInputValue', {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true,
            field: 'id'
        },
        formInputID: {
            type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'formInputID'
        },
        inputValue: {
            type: DataTypes.ARRAY(DataTypes.STRING),
            allowNull: false,
            field: 'inputValue'
        }
    }, {
        tableName: 'formInputValue',
        timestamps: false
    });
};
```

I would like to create this instance but stops running when I try to add an array of values to `inputValues`. Any soutions?

Comment: What is the model definition of `formInputValue`?

Comment: Just added the model.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have a query operator `[Op.in]` in your create?

```
formInputValue.create({
    formInputID: formInput.id,
    inputValue: {
        [Op.in]: inputValues
    }
})
```

If you remove that, and your `inputValues` is an array of strings (as defined by your model) it should create them. See below with that operator removed.

```
formInputValue.create({
    formInputID: formInput.id,
    inputValue: inputValues
})
```

Comment: I figured it out. The reason we are using [Op.in] is because we are receiving an array. We have not figured out how to receive an array another way.